# NUC playing Intel jingle while boxed, should I be worried?

Tags: hardware-failure, intel-nuc

I bought an Intel NUC (D34010WYK, to be exact) used, as an Amazon Warehouse Deal. It's supposed to come with a 128GB SSD and 4 GB of RAM already installed.

It still resides in its original packaging, so I haven't connected it to anything yet (not even mains).

Yet bizarrely, it keeps playing the Intel jingle (da-di-da-ding, you know the tune) whenever it is moved or shaken!

Should I return the unit, or is this normal behaviour for a unit that has already been used?

Comment: This may get massively annoying if a pallet of em starts playing out of sync at once

Comment: @JourneymanGeek totally. The damn thing has been playing about every hour all night - perhaps because of the high temperatures, I don't know. A pallet of them must be a nightmare.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7_I3LI8tSQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *packaging* is what is playing the Jingle.  The packaging uses the same super-advanced technology as the audio greeting cards, a small battery and speaker on a tiny PCB.  It plays automatically when the packaging is moved.  Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Urgh. Yeah, I can see the speaker now. What a funny, yet crazy idea. Thanks!

Comment: Cut the red wire?

Comment: Seems like it's only supposed to happen when you open it, so yours is probably a little faulty @Pekka (as Keltari said, just the packaging, not the NUC itself)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek NO!  CUT THE BLUE WIRE!